# How to put a Image/Logo on the Nav bar?

Tags: html, css

How do i put a logo/image in my Navigation bar that leads to my homepage? I want the Logo on the Left and my text links (Home, Download) on the left? really confused and stumped.

Comment: Did you code anything so far for your homepage? Any example, or... something?

Comment: I am confused and stumped by your question too.

Comment: Give us more info please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it for example this way

```
<div id="logo" style="background-image:
    url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg/150px-Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg.png');
    width: 50px; height: 50px; background-size: contain; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat; float: left">
</div>

<div class="nav" style="float:left; margin-left: 30px; margin-top: 10px;">
    <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home">Home</a>
</div>

<div class="nav" style="float:left; margin-left: 30px; margin-top: 10px;">
    <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Download">Downloads</a>
</div>
```

-> https://jsfiddle.net/p307zybo/1/